# socket - using select for timeout

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I'm trying to learn sockets. so far I succeeded to open a socket (as server), connect, and send and receive some data.
Now I'm trying to put a limit of waiting time in `accept()` function.
I found a few code example, but I don't have any success for now:

```
      //socket, bind...
      listen(this->sockfd, 1);

      int iResult;
      struct timeval tv;
      fd_set rfds;
      FD_ZERO(&rfds);
      FD_SET(0, &rfds);

      tv.tv_sec = 5;
      iResult = select(0, &rfds, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, &tv);
      if(iResult > 0)
      {
          std::cout<< "connected"<<endl;
      } else {
          std::cout<< "time out!" << endl;
      }
```

I always get "time out!".
 Can you put the finger on what wrong? Thanks

Comment: file descriptor 0 is for STDIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
FD_SET(0, &rfds);
// ...
iResult = select(0, &rfds, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, &tv);
```

to

```
FD_SET(this->sockfd, &rfds);
// ...
iResult = select(this->sockfd + 1, &rfds, nullptr, nullptr, &tv);
```